# How to tag specific text?

Tags: text, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to tag specific text that shows on my website. For example, if someone clicks on the button and then the pop-up shows with the sentence.

Is there a possibility to tag this sentence in the pop-up window? I cannot use URL, because it does not change and also I do not have any classes or IDs.

So I want to fire the tag only when a specific sentence shows on the site.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to track the button that launches the popup ? You could do that with a click event.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title quite literally (not that I think the following is a good idea) :

Create a custom HTML tag that is fired on a page with after the DOM has loaded (since you want to evaluate text you need to wait until the text is actually displayed, so you cannot fire the tag on pageLoad).

Enter the following code:

```
<script>
if(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML.indexOf('myText') > -1) {
dataLayer.push('event':'myTextIsPresent');
}
</script>
```

(replace 'myText' with the actual text your are looking for. And some older Browsers might not support getElementsByTagName). This loads the whole HTML body into a variable and indexOf looks of your desired text is present (if yes it returns a positive int or 0, if not it returns -1).

Create a trigger with the type of custom event where event name is myTextIsPresent.

Fire your tags with the new trigger.

Now this has a lot more disadvantages that I care to elaborate (you dump a big amount of text into the browser memory, you can fire tags only on DOM ready etc) but it is possible.

However it is a much better idea not to look at the text but to trigger tags with some user interaction (like the button click that launches the popup).